# How to replace text value and keep the data type with using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas

My dataset contains **" '000 "** in the beginning of the values.

I have used `df = df.replace({"'":""}, regex=True)` to remove '
However, it will change the data type and remove **000** automatically.
Is there any method to keep 000?

Comment: `df['column'] = df['column'].str.strip("'")`

Comment: `df.replace({"'": ""}, regex=True)` does not change the dtype for me.

Comment: But as a back up plan `df.applymap(lambda s: s.lstrip("'"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can typecast the column values as strings then removing the apostrophe by using `.replace()` method for strings:

```
# Typecast the column values as strings
df['column'] = df['column'].astype(str)

# Place the values in a list
zero_zero_list = df['column'].values.tolist()

# Use list comprehension to remove the apostrophe only and retain the zeroes
remove_apostrophe_list = [x.replace("\'","") for x in zero_zero_list]

# Use the resulting list as the new value of your column
df['column'] = remove_apostrophe_list
```